# Get name from value in R (setNames example)

Tags: r, shiny

How can I extract corresponding NAME_X based on the value.

```
CHOICES <- setNames(c(0, 1), c("NAME_1", "NAME_2"))
```

For example `get_name(0)` should return `"NAME_1"` and `get_name(1)` should return `"NAME_2"`.
To provide context, I am using those choices in `selectInput` of my Shiny app.

Comment: Perhaps you need `names(CHOICES[CHOICES == 0])`. Or if you only deal with `0`s and `1`s you can try `names(CHOICES)[CHOICES]` or `names(CHOICES)[!CHOICES]`

Comment: Thanks @markus `names(CHOICES[CHOICES == 0])` is what I needed. I have values apart from `0s` and `1s`, in fact sometimes I have strings.